# In python, what is the difference between random.uniform() and random.random()?

Tags: python, random, uniform

In python for the random module, what is the difference between `random.uniform()` and `random.random()`? They both generate pseudo random numbers, `random.uniform()` generates numbers from a uniform distribution and `random.random()` generates the next random number. What is the difference?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)? `random.uniform(0, 1)` is the same as `random.random()`.

Comment: There is a difference, due to  floating-point rounding  you can sometimes hit the upper bound in uniform

Comment: Actually according to the documentation they are not the same...

Answer (score 102):

`random.random()` gives you a random floating point number in the range `[0.0, 1.0)` (so including `0.0`, but not including `1.0` which is also known as a semi-open range). `random.uniform(a, b)` gives you a random floating point number in the range `[a, b]`, (where rounding may end up giving you `b`).

The [implementation of `random.uniform()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/376c2d81d0e2/Lib/random.py#l356) uses `random.random()` directly:

```
def uniform(self, a, b):
    "Get a random number in the range [a, b) or [a, b] depending on rounding."
    return a + (b-a) * self.random()
```

`random.uniform(0, 1)` is basically the same thing as `random.random()` (as `1.0` times *float value closest to `1.0`* still will give you *float value closest to `1.0`* there is no possibility of a rounding error there).

Answer (score 11):

In **random.random()**  the output lies between 0 & 1 , and it takes no input parameters

Whereas **random.uniform()** takes parameters , wherein you can submit the range of the random number.
e.g.
`import random as ra
 print ra.random()
 print ra.uniform(5,10)`

OUTPUT:-
`0.672485369423
 7.9237539416`

Answer (score 11):

Apart from what is being mentioned above, `.uniform()` can also be used for generating multiple random numbers that too with the desired shape which is not possible with `.random()`

```
np.random.seed(99)
np.random.random()

#generates 0.6722785586307918
```

while the following code

```
np.random.seed(99)
np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, size = (5,2))

#generates this 
array([[0.67227856, 0.4880784 ],
       [0.82549517, 0.03144639],
       [0.80804996, 0.56561742],
       [0.2976225 , 0.04669572],
       [0.9906274 , 0.00682573]])
```

This can't be done with random(...), and if you're generating the random(...) numbers for ML related things, most of the time, you'll end up using `.uniform(...)`

Comment: This is for numpy's random module, which is different than the Python stdlib's random module.  Still, very useful to know!

Comment: What is np in this code? Also, I tried using `random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, size = (5,2))` and was given an error that size was an unexpected keyword argument.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is in the arguments. It's very common to generate a random number from a uniform distribution in the range [0.0, 1.0), so [`random.random()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random) just does this. Use [`random.uniform(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform) to specify a different range.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation on [`random.uniform`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform):

> Return a random floating point number N such that a <= N <= b for a <= b and b <= N <= a for b < a.

while [`random.random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random):

> Return the next random floating point number in the range [0.0, 1.0).

I.e. with `random.uniform` you specify a range you draw pseudo-random numbers from, e.g. between 3 and 10. With `random.random` you get a number between 0 and 1.